geometric mean and mean value of derivative of strictly increasing convex function

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an analytic function such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$. I want to prove that there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>\sqrt{f'(a)f'(b)}$.

To solve this problem, I tried the following:
Assume that $f(0)=0$ and $a=0$. Then, it suffices to show that there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{x^2 f'(x)f'(0)}{(f(x))^2}<1$$
I tried a lot of example (ex. $e^x, e^{e^x}, \cdots)$ and this is my claim:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2f'(x)}{f(x)^2} = 0$$ It implies that if we choose sufficiently large $x>0$, then we achieve the desired result. But I don't know how to prove my claim rigorously.

Am I missing something? $f = e^{x}$ satisfies $f', f'' > 0$ and analytic. Then taking $a = 0$, for the inequality to hold you require $$b^{-1} (e^{b} - 1) > e^{b/2} \implies \sinh({b/2}) > b/2$$ which holds for all $b > 0$. So choose $f = e^{x}, a = 0, b \in (0, \infty)$.

Your example is correct, but what I want is an identification and proof of whether we can get the same result for a general analytic function that satisfies $f'>0$ and $f''>0$.
